# OnItemClickListener not triggering if I have onTouchListener unless I scroll?

Tags: android, android-listview, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

In my Activity I have a list view,for that I have both `onItemClickListener` and `onTouchListener`. When I click a row in my `list.OnTouch` method called for `MotionEvent` `Down` and `Up`. For both the cases I return "false" since I don't want to handle touch event but only want to observe it. At this moment I expect `onItemClick` should have called but it not happening. But if I move my list view, the `OnTouch` motion event "move" has been called,and after that if I click an item it get triggered. So why my `itemClick` not triggered initially and why it has triggered after the movement in list view ?

code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Handler rHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("An Item is clicked not touched");
        }

    });
      rHandler = new Handler(this,lv);
    }


 }
```

I am populating custom ListView lv in a adapter and that list row consists textViews and imageViews.Also I have some onclick events on imageViews.So, I have tried android:focusable and android:focusableInTouchMode set to false in imageView.But not succeeded.

In Handler.java

```
public class Handler implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public Handler(Context mContext,ListView lv) {
       lv.setOnTouchListener(this);
     }

     @Override
      public final boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            System.out.println(" Motion ... ");
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            System.out.println(" Motion Down ");
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            System.out.println(" Motion Up ");
            break;
        }
        }
        System.out.println("I am returning false");
        return false;
      }
     }
```

My OnItemClick came to active once I click image onClick events or if I moved my list.Looks very strange!!!

Comment: post your code snippet..

Answer (score 2):

yes it is not called.
What you can do is

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            break;         
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;   

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            if(!mIsTouchHandeled){
                int position = mChatListView.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                if(position!=ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
                    mChatListView.performItemClick(mChatListView.getChildAt(position-mChatListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()), position, mChatListView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
                }
            }
            break;
        }           
        //       return super.onTouchEvent(event);       


        return false;
    }

}
```

Basically I am finding on action up that if touch work is not done I will call my OnItemClick by performClick method.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You should return super.onTouchEvent(event); instead i of return false. By retruning false your are telling the system that you dont want touch events for your View and therefore the onClickEvent is ignored.